# como hago un reporte individual con crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

como le hago para crear un reporte con Crystal Report de una tabla, pero necesito que me aparezca un registro por hojas ?

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que al archivo de reporte(rpt) agregues un campo de grupo a ese campo le asignas el id de esa tabla y en la pestaña de opciones cliqueas la opcion de nueva pagina despues de: y ahi colocas 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok, ensayando me funciono, tengo un problemita y es que me esta cargando datos que no son. En el DataGridView aparecen bien, pero en el reporte aparecen otros.

Comment: y utilizas la misma consulta o procedimiento para llenar el DataGridView y el reporte?

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado, me aparecen los registros que necesito. Usando el rdlc con el reportviewer no veo la opción de poder el informe con registros individuales, con el crystalreport si.